# How to apply Bayesian learning to paired data

Tags: bayesian

This might be a beginner's question, but I can't find a good answer elsewhere.

Suppose I have some prior distribution $P(E|H)$ representing how likely a certain value $e \in E$ is, given some precondition $h \in H$. I want to improve this distribution by making some observations $\{(h_0, e_0), (h_1, e_1), \dots\}$. How do I update $P$ with these new observations?

Comment: $P(E|H)$ is the likelihood function.  A prior would be of the form $P(H)$.  Likewise, $H$ is not observed.  Because of that, you would not have a pairing such as $(h,e).$  You could have $E$ be of binary nature such as $(x,y)$ and $H$ could be a number of things such as a vector or set.  An example of this may be $(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: Is your real question about how to manage a mapping from $x\to{y}$ given unobservable parameters?

Comment: @DaveHarris, maybe I have not expressed my question well. But I actually mean that my prior is $P(E|H)$. Let us assume I have already learned by some means and have arrived at that function. If you want to simplify, we can even assume that $P(E|H) = P(E)$, i.e. it is independent of $H$, i.e. we don't know yet at all how to predict $E$ from $H$.

Answer (score 4):

I think your notation is getting in the way of an answer.  $E$ is usually used for *evidence* and $H$ is usually used for *hypothesis*.  It appears you are using them as variables.  You cannot form a prior on a variable, $(x,y)$ as variables are constants in Bayesian thinking.  If you have observed something, then there is no uncertainty regarding it.  It isn't actually variable.  If you saw that it was 45 degrees yesterday at noon, there is no randomness involved.  It was 45 degrees at noon.  You cannot form a probability distribution around a fact.

Let me create an example for you.  Let us imagine that you are concerned with the accounting ratio $\gamma=\frac{\text{accounts receivable}}{\text{sales}}$.  In particular, you are the CEO of your company, and you have a meeting in the morning.  Your accounting department is closed, but you just got off a call from your sales manager with sales figures, and you need an estimate of receivables.

This may not be the best example because it is implicitly assuming quite a bit of stability.  Nonetheless, let us work with $x=\text{sales}$ and $y=\text{accounts receivable}$.  Another way to map this is as $$y=\gamma{x}+\epsilon.$$  Since it is an example, let us assume that $\epsilon$ is normally distributed.  We have past observations of $(x,y)$.  We do not know $\gamma$.

Our likelihood function is $\mathcal{N}(y-\gamma{x},\sigma^2)$.  We will denote the likelihood $f((x,y)|\gamma;\sigma^2)$.  Our prior would be about what we believe $\gamma$ and $\sigma^2$ to be.  Ignoring existing data and working from information from outside your data set, what is the relative probability of each value of $\gamma$ and $\sigma^2$.  We will denote the prior $\pi(\gamma,\sigma^2)$.

The posterior density would be $$\pi’(\gamma,\sigma^2|(x_1,y_1)\dots(x_I,y_I))=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^If((x_i,y_i)|\gamma;\sigma^2)\pi(\gamma;\sigma^2)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^\infty\prod_{i=1}^If((x_i,y_i)|\gamma;\sigma^2)\pi(\gamma;\sigma^2)\mathrm{d}\gamma\mathrm{d}\sigma^2}.$$

Now that we have a posterior, we can create a prediction based on prior observations and our prior *outside* knowledge regarding the location of the parameters. We can now form a prediction regarding this month’s receivables.
It would be $$\pi''(y=Y|x=X;(x_1,y_1)\dots{(x_I,y_I)})=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^\infty{f}((x=X,Y)|\gamma;\sigma^2)\pi’(\gamma;\sigma^2|(x_1,y_1)\dots(x_I,y_I))\mathrm{d}\gamma\mathrm{d}\sigma^2.$$

Comment: Yes, I think the issue was that I confused a likelihood probability parameter with a probability distribution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion between two concepts:

- An unknown likelihood parameter, such as a general probability of some kind of event occuring, which we want to estimate by means of observations
- The probability distribution of this parameter, given certain specific events having occurred.

### Biased coins

As an example, take the [example of a flipped coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Example). There is a coin which we can flip, but the probability of landing heads is unknown since the coin might be biased. That is, there is a certain unknown probability $p$ of the coin landing heads, which we would like to learn about.

Our prior is that we have no knowledge about $p$, i.e. a constant probability density $P(p) = 1$. (This integrates to $\int_0^1 P(p) dp = 1$, so the normalisation is correct.) We now want to get a new distribution after throwing the coin.

Assume the coin landed on heads ($H$). We are looking for the distribution $P(p | H)$. This distribution tells us how likely it is for the coin to land on heads, given that we've now seen it land on heads once. By Bayes' theorem, we have:

$$P(p | H) = \frac{P(H | p)}{P(H)} \cdot P(p)$$

$P(p)$ is 1, since we assumed no knowledge about the bias of the coin. Tautologically, $P(H | p)$ is the probability of the coin landing on heads, given that the probability of it landing on heads is $p$. By definition, this is simply $p$ itself. The probability $P(H)$ is the probability of landing on heads for any value of $p$. This is computed as an integral:

$$P(H) = \int_0^1 P(H|p) dp = \int_0^1 pdp = \frac{1}{2}$$

So the new probability distribution is:

$$ P(p | H) = 2p $$
Clearly, a high probability of landing on heads is favoured now, and the case of $p = 0$ is ruled out.

When we perform more experiments, this distribution becomes a binomial distribution.

### Indoor/outdoor ornithology

I originally stumbled across my question when trying to understand the [Raven paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven_paradox), but my problem was one step earlier already. My question is roughly:

*"Assume we can observe some animals, such as ravens, frogs, bugs, ..., and their colours (black, green, ...). After having done some observations, someone tells us they saw a raven. What is the probability of it being black?"*

Basically, I want to estimate a probability $p(\text{Black}|\text{Raven})$, after having made some observations of the form $(\text{colour}_i, \text{animal}_i)$. Note that my observations are only about *correlation*, not causation (the cause of an animal being of a particular species influencing its colour).

To estimate that probability, I actually want to start with the probability distribution $p_{c,a}$, i.e. estimate the correlation between **c**olours and **a**nimals. So I actually have to estimate a distribution over a space of many parameters, instead of a 1-dimensional space like in the previous example. Every observation $(c_i, a_i)$ updates that distribution, and in the end I get probabilities for different values of $p_{c,a}$.

Answer (score 0):

To make things less abstract, you need a model. Let's say you assume a linear model.

$$
e \sim a \cdot h + r\\
r \sim \mathrm{N}(\mu, \sigma)  
$$

This specifies the distribution of $e$ given $h$, if you have some priors on the variables, $a$, $\mu$ and $\sigma$. Now after observing actual data, you can start updating your prior on all these variables to get the posterior of all those variables. If you have such a posterior, and you know a new $h$, you can calculate a posterior distribution for $e$ as well. Note that it can be quite hard to calculate a posterior, that's why you'd need a *sampler* program for all but some specifically constructed models.

The confusion in your comments seems to arise from the idea that you already have a complete function, like $e = h^2 + 5$, and that that function can then be updated somehow. But a function is fixed, it needs some parameters that are not fixed, for which you have priors, like above, so that you can update them.

The structure of the function, if you will, in the case above, the multiplication and addition, are not updated. It is actually also possible to have some prior over a set of functions, but that's making things more complicated.